# Cover Time for Random Walk on a cycle

Tags: random-walk, random-graphs

I'm trying to find the expected time to cover all $N$ nodes on an undirected cycle graph, starting from a given node $k$. The probabilities of moving clockwise and anticlockwise are $\frac{1}{2}$ each.

Could you direct me to some entry-level texts/resources which would explain this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is example 11.1 in *Markov Chains and Mixing Times* by Levin, Peres, and Wilmer. The book is available online [here](http://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/markovmixing.pdf).

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed.